# How to set position inside framelayout?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a image an text inside a framelayout i move the text using padding but when i run the emulator the textView stay in the corne, how can i correct this?

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/ruleta6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="39dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView17"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView18">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_roulette"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="actionRoulette"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ruletaestrella"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="25dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="330dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/castigo1a"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:rotation="20"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="#fc0000"
        android:textSize="20dp" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `FrameLayout` has `0dp` for height and width. You should make it `match_parent` on both or bigger than `0dp`. Then you can use `layout_gravity` and `gravity` tags on your `TextView` to push it around, center it in `FrameLayout` and etc. For that to work tho your `FrameLayout` has to be larger than `TextView`.

---

**Example:**

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="TextView"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

**Note:** `android:gravity` sets position of Layout children and `android:layout_gravity` sets position of the Layout/View in his parent.

---

Good luck :)

Comment: It is just and example where those parameters should be put :)

Comment: hey! thanks already change the code and the text still in the corner :/

Comment: @pentaaax Try `wrap_content` on `TextView` and take a look at your `ConstraintLayout` constraints, it might have an effect on layout behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Try to fix below error.
- FrameLayout width and Height both set as 0 dp, it should be either MATCH_PARENT , WRAP_CONTENT or some fix value 
** 0 dp width or height is only possible in LinearLayout and that is only for either width or height exclusively with define weight.

Comment: alredy fix that but the content still in the corner :/